# Can a shaman change her chosen hexes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, shaman

I am currently playing a 6th level Shaman and I think I chose my hexes poorly according to our campaign. Is it possible to change what hexes a Shaman knows according to the Pathfinder rules, similar to prepared spells and spirits?

Or is it "you chose it, now stick to it"?

Comment: When you say 'similar to X' do you mean 'once daily without cost as they feel like it, and certainly not by using the retraining rules' or do you mean 'by any means' and the similar part is referring just to the fact that they can be changed?

Comment: I more meant the fact that it can be changed without the GM saying "Okay, if you really have to"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but not nearly so painlessly.

There are [retraining rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining/) designed to allow you to fix such choices.  The process takes 5 days per hex and 50*your level in gp per hex.

Comment: Wonderful, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Also take note that these rules are optional, so discuss that with your GM before using them! (there shouldn't be any problem as long as you just want to fix poor previous choices)